# What is the style name of AlertDialog.Builder positive button?

Tags: android, dialog, styles, android-alertdialog

What is the style name that AlertDialog.Builder uses for the positive/negative buttons?

I want to use the style for a custom DialogFragment.

The code I found for AlertDialog.Builder.setPositivebutton(...) is the following, but I don't know how to find out the style this button uses from there. How can I find out the style?

```
       public Builder setPositiveButton(CharSequence text, final OnClickListener listener) {
            P.mPositiveButtonText = text;
            P.mPositiveButtonListener = listener;
            return this;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably too late, but if you take a look [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/alert_dialog.xml), you'll find that the style the buttons have is specified in android's *buttonBarButtonStyle* attribute.

or

with material design, the styles are as follows:

```
style="?attr/buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle"
style="?attr/buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle"
style="?attr/buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle"
```